# How to get profile picture from Microsoft Graph API using Keycloak token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, keycloak

I am trying to get profile picture from Microsoft Graph API using keycloak token.

But it is getting unauthorised when I use keycloak token, if i use token from Microsoft identity it is working fine and returning profile picture.

I am unable to get proper documentation on this. Please share if anybody got/have.

Comment: Microsoft GraphApi require you to use [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens) to call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I have found this question in official keycloak blog and is really helpful to proceed.
https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/is-it-possible-to-use-an-keycloak-accesstoken-to-get-access-to-the-microsoft-graph/6831

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute a [token exchange](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_token-exchange), where you exchange Keycloak token (not valid for Microsoft Graph API) for a Microsoft token (valid for Microsoft Graph API).