# 400 bad request when requesting Microsoft access token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, keycloak

I am trying to fetch User profile picture from Microsoft Graph API by using keycloak access token. But I am getting the following error from keycloak API

```
{
    "errorMessage": "Invalid token."
}
```

API - http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{Realm name}/broker/{identity provider}/token

Header - Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get profile picture from Microsoft Graph API using Keycloak token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72451551/how-to-get-profile-picture-from-microsoft-graph-api-using-keycloak-token)

Comment: No Jan Garaj, actually after trying that.. i am facing this issue.

Comment: Hi @Suryaprakash
How are you checking the token?